Real path of a directory in Android device
I can see by means of Android file explorer the 'Pictures' folder. I want to display programmatically the first picture in that folder. How can I get a real path to it?
I tried a
FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'Pictures/'
but that path doesn't exist.
I see it, but I cannot get it. That's so upset.

try this path
    path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

there is also Media store API. read THIS doc about storing/accessing data

I appreciate you help, but I mean internal, local 'Pictures' directory.

@IgorSeliverstov: What you think of as "internal" is what the Android SDK refers to as "external".

And how can I make it with expo library?

As I know, expo-file-system only allows access to app specific directories, not system wide folders like Pictures.
expo-media-library is the correct approach for accessing device media files outside your app’s sandbox. It is worth a try imo.

All right. I see local android 'Notifications' folder on my device. (it contains no media files). How can I access it (i.e. get its path)?
